# How to add number of observation and Median per group in boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

Probably my question may be a duplicate, but I am unable to do it in `ggplot2` (`tidyverse`) only?

I want to add count of number of observations and median to each group/element of a box-plot in `ggplot2`

Here is the reprex

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- iris %>% sample_n(100)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = ifelse(Sepal.Width > mean(Sepal.Width), 'Gr-1', 'Gr-2')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = grp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ grp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Expected outcome something like this for all 6 boxes

[image]

Comment: may help https://gscheithauer.medium.com/how-to-add-number-of-observations-to-a-ggplot2-boxplot-b22710f7ef80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution taken from an [article](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/275-add-text-labels-with-ggplot2.html). For this purpose we can make use of `stat_summary` function, but for its `fun.data` we have to create a custom function that calculates count and median. It should be noted that we use `geom_text` in `stat_summary` so it requires `x` or `y` and `label` argument. So when we write our custom `stat_box_sum` function we have to make sure that the resulting data frame has these aesthetics as column names:

```
stat_box_sum <- function(y, upper_limit = max(iris$Sepal.Length)) {
  DF <- data.frame(
    y = max(y),
    label = paste("N:", length(y), "\n",
                  "Median:", median(y), "\n")
  )
  DF
}

stat_box_sum(iris$Sepal.Length)
    y                    label
1 7.9 N: 150 \n Median: 5.8 \n

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = ifelse(Sepal.Width > mean(Sepal.Width), 'Gr-1', 'Gr-2')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, fill = grp)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ grp) + 
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = stat_box_sum, 
               geom = "text", 
    hjust = 0.7,
    vjust = 0.7)
```

[image]
The only remaining problem I suppose is the adjustment of labels which I try to figure out soon.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful solution.  I will also try to position labels as per fixed y coordinate

Comment: If only I could solve the position problem.